# How to solve integral over n-dimensional sphere

Tags: spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

Let $f(r)$ be a function of $r = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}}$ and $n\geq3$. How do I solve the following integral:
$$\int_{\partial B(0,\epsilon)}f(r)dS(r)$$ with $dS(r)$ as the element of a n-dimensional ball with radius $\epsilon$ and $f(r)=\frac{1}{r^{n-2}}$.

I don`t really understand how to write the integral above in simpler form. Any hint to convert the integral into simpler form is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ depends only on $r$, it is constant on the sphererical surface. The value of the integral is then $f(\epsilon)$ times the surface of the sphere, which is $\Omega_n\,\epsilon^{n-1}$, where $\Omega_n$ is the measure of the $n-1$-dimensional sphere.

Comment: thank you! but can you explain also if $f(r,\theta)$ is being integrated? To be precise... what is the explicit formula of $dS$ in n-spherical coordinate? Thanks again!

Comment: Look for $n$-dimensional sphererical coordinates.